# Xcode 7.3.1 project crashed and now hung while opening

Tags: xcode, swift, crash, hung

I was modifying some autolayout constraints and Xcode was starting to slow down in terms of response time. Then it crashed. I have since tried :
1. reopening the project
2. reopening another project
2. rebooting and reopening

Everything I've tried -->Xcode just hangs.

What do you guys recommend?  Should I uninstall xcode and reinstall it?

xcode 7.3.1
osx el capitan.  10.11.14
thanks

Comment: have you looked at the console output?  I'm having a similar problem.. and I think in my case it's related to code signing. I get a `cs_invalid_page` error... I'm also using 7.3.1 on el capitan 10.11.16